# Azure Import Error: The internal target platform type SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider does not support schema file version '3.1'

Tags: sql-server, azure, bacpac

For some reasons I cannot import new BACPACs from Azure. I still can import old ones.
This is the error message I get:

```
Internal Error.  The internal target platform type SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider does not support schema file version '3.1'.
```

I've tried this [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754023/sql-azure-v12-bacpac-import-error-the-internal-target-platform-type-sqlazurev1) , but it didn't help, because all my settings are already set up to default.
I also downloaded latest [SSMS Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx), but on import it gives me other errors:

```
Warning SQL0: A project which specifies Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server 2014.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'Admin'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Admin]
    WITH IDENTITY = N'Admin';

Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Admin]
    WITH IDENTITY = N'Admin';
```

I have SSMS 2014 CU6 installed.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out what happened. It's a specific case, but maybe it helps someone else.
We tried to use [elasic query](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-vertical-partitioning/) to write queries across databases. To do it you need to create database scoped credentials. When package was imported, it tried to do the same locally and failed executing this:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Admin]
WITH IDENTITY = N'Admin';
```

Since we decided to use different approach, I dropped scoped credentials and external data source (couldn't drop credentials without dropping data source):

```
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Source
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL Admin
```

Now everything is working again. Just be aware you cannot import database from Azure if it has scoped credentials created.

Comment: your answer saved me.

Comment: I am glad:) Spent almost 2 day to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the new SQL Server Management Studio
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Hey Ronen! Thank you for the reply, but I already wrote in my question, that I downloaded latest SSMS preview, and still getting errors - just different errors (they are also in the question),

Comment: OK, I noticed only the use of SSMS 2014 CU6. I did not notice that you tried the 2016 preview

Comment: Tried all solutions I could find. No luck yet.